# Rails, gem with functionality in between enum and many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

i have im my rails app model which has few options (no more than 10 i think).
Something like Product - Category, where product can be part of 1 or many categories.
But i think i have too few categories to engage fully fledged many-to-many construct.
Moreover the list of categroies is predefined and will almost never change.

I think from sql side this could look like string field `categories` with such content:`"Fruits|Vegetables|..."`

Maybe someone know preexisting gem for such functionality, or maybe it is no real advantage doing so and i should choose standart `many-to-many` ?

I checked `acts-as-taggable-on` plugin, but it is i think fits not very well for this task.

Enum gems like `enumerize` i think fit just best, but they are allow only single single value to be choosen.

Comment: Enumerize's readme now has an example for multiple values to be chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently came out with following combination:

This gem:
https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu

In model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  KINDS =  { 1 => :fruit, 2 => :vegetable }
  include FlagShihTzu
  attr_accessible *KINDS.values
  as_flags KINDS
```

Then in view (haml):

```
    =form_for [@product] do |f|
      -Product::KINDS.each do |k, v|
        =f.check_box v
        =f.label v
```

UPDATE:

Yet another gem adressing this problem: https://github.com/joelmoss/bitmask_attributes

Comment: With the last several releases of flag_shih_tzu, the `attr_accessible *KINDS.values` should no longer be required.  The exact same methods are generated by flag_shih_tzu by default.